# How Javascript functions are called through other objects?

Tags: javascript

First of all sorry for the vague title; couldn't think of a more appropriate wording. I'm relatively new to Javascript and web programming in general (although season in .NET desktop programming). I have been looking at the following coding pattern repeatedly in JS, especially with library functions such as jQuery UI:

```
$("#MyDiv").dialog({ ... });
```

My question is (thinking like a C# programmer), what is the type of `$("#MyDiv")`? How does `dialog()` become a member of this type? I can see that `dialog()` is defined in jQuery UI library and can be dynamically attached to any object. What's the magic here? What's C# equivalent of this; Extension methods?

Also, is there a way to get reference of the calling object inside this "attached" function?

Comment: `$("#MyDiv")` is a type that belongs to the jQuery library, its not pure Javascript. think of jQuery as a collection of extension methods , like Linq in c#

Comment: Typically, you can reference the calling object (from the method) using `this`. For example, $('#mydiv').dialog({ ... }) => `this` is typically the DOM element (`#mydiv`) or a jQuery object representing the selection.

Comment: More information on constructor functions and prototype can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 even though you call jquery ($) without new, a new jquery instance is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick breakdown of:

```
$("#MyDiv").dialog({ ... });
```

1. `$` is a function.  Though it looks like a special symbol, it's just a plain old javascript function.
2. That function takes the argument `"#MyDiv"` and creates and returns a jQuery object.
3. The jQuery UI library has made sure that all jQuery objects that are created have a method called `.dialog()` by adding that to the prototype of jQuery objects (an extension mechanism jQuery uses).
4. So, the `.dialog()` part is calling the `.dialog()` method on the jQuery object that was just created and returned by the previous function.

---

In sequential steps:

1. Call the `$` function and pass it the `"#MyDiv"` selector argument.
2. The `$` function creates a jQuery object and looks up that selector and stores any DOM objects that match that selector in that jQuery object.
3. The `$` function then returns this new jQuery object.
4. That jQuery object is then searched for a method called `.dialog()` and when that method is found it is executed on that object as in `obj.method()`.
5. The `.dialog()` method looks at the jQuery object it was called on (which the `this` pointer is set to) and it looks at the arguments passed to the `.dialog()` method and acts accordingly.

Comment: Insightful. Thanks a bundle.

Comment: the closest c# alternative for the selector i can think of is a lambda expression, as in `(object = > object.ID=="MyDiv")`, where '#' would be .ID, and '.' would be .Class, and no prefix would be .Type

Answer (score 2):

`$("#MyDiv")` returns a jQuery object, and `dialog` is a method of the jQuery class.

Unlike languages like C++, Javascript allows methods to be added to classes on the fly. So when you load the jQuery UI library, it adds the `dialog` method to the jQuery class.

Inside the method, the special variable `this` contains a reference to the object that it was called on.

Comment: There is no jQuery "class" o_O

Comment: If it quacks like a duck. :)

Comment: Thanks. For unclear reasons, I like this answer more. :)